# Join tables where inluding null values on THIRD table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on e-dictionary and i have 2 tables:

First table: Term

```
+----+--------------+
| id | term_text    |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | hello        |
| 2  | how are you? |
| 3  | hola         |
+----+--------------+
```

Second table: Dictionary

```
<pre>
+-----------+------------+
| term_id_1 | term_id_2  |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | 3          | /* hello - hola
| 2         | NULL       | /* how are you? - NULL
+-----------+------------+
</pre>
```

I want to display like this:

```
<pre>


+--------------+-------------+
| term_text_1  | term_text_2 |
+--------------+-------------+
| hello        | hola        | 
| how are you? | NULL        | 
+--------------+-------------+

</pre>
```

I was trying to get data using following query:

```
<pre>
SELECT t1.term_text_1, t2.term_text_2
FROM dictionary d, term t1, term t2
WHERE d.term_id_1 = t1.id
AND d.term_id_2 = t2.id
</pre>
```

But i was getting only where value is not null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `dictionary` with `term` twice:

```
select 
  t1.term_text term_text_1,
  t2.term_text term_text_2
from dictionary 
left join term t1 on t1.id = term_id_1 
left join term t2 on t2.id = term_id_2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/48HLocsp1wmsEAe3entUrE/0).
Results:

```
| term_text_1  | term_text_2 |
| ------------ | ----------- |
| hello        | hola        |
| how are you? |             |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT t1.term_text as term_text_1, t2.term_text as term_text_2
FROM dictionary d
LEFT JOIN term t1 ON d.term_id_1 = t1.id
LEFT JOIN term t2 ON d.term_id_2 = t2.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/GRMM18124)</kbd>